# Serve index from subfolder in nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, redirect

I have an app that's structured like this:

```
app/
app/index.html
app/foo.js
app/assets/
file.php
anotherfile.php
etc.php
```

With Apache, I would put the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/app\/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/$1 [QSA]
```

In other words, if the request URI does not contain `/app/` and the requested file is not an actual file, then rewrite to `app`. So if someone went to https://my.example.url/#/login then they would be served https://my.example.url/app/index.html#/login without noticing.

I'm investigating switching over to nginx and am trying to replicate this behavior. What I've got so far isn't working:

```
location ~ \/app\/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files app/$uri $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

I would expect it to look for an index.html file in /, not find it since it isn;t there, and then look for it in the app folder, but instead nginx just throws a 403 forbidden error since I've got `autoindex` off.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `/app$uri` as all Nginx URIs begin with a `/` and the variable `$uri` already includes a leading `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing

```
index index.html;
```

directive in your configuration. This one tells nginx to try append `index.html` for URIs that end with slash, like `/app/`.